# Trouble Activating TensorFlow-GPU in New Virtual Environment

Tags: tensorflow

I'm currently facing an issue with activating TensorFlow-GPU in a new virtual environment. I've followed the steps of creating a new environment, installing CUDA Toolkit, cuDNN, and TensorFlow-GPU, but unfortunately, the GPU is not being recognized.
I have checked the compatibility of CUDA Toolkit, cuDNN, and TensorFlow versions. Additionally, I've verified that my GPU drivers are up to date, and the necessary environment variables are set.

When I run the following code:
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
expected to see my GPU listed, but it's not recognized.

I have already tried reinstalling TensorFlow and other ppossible solutions. However, the issue persists.

Comment: Could you please add the versions of the different libraries you're mentioning, as well as your OS? Thanks

Comment: Can u give us the command u executed? You can find [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu) the version of each library that need to be installed.